# ¿Como se plantea un buen tablero?

Tags: java

Ya quise hacer dos juegos en java pero no los pude terminar por no tener idea de como se diseñan bien.
Tengo varias preguntas, todas masomenos, apuntando al mismo lado:

1.¿Como diseño bien el tablero? ¿Se hace en un array unidimensional o bi(x-y) cada uno con las instancias de los sprites correspondientes?

2.¿A los "tiles" como hago para que tengan un listener del mouse? Hasta ahora ese fue mi mayor problema(se me ocurrió ver el click de mouse x,y y comparado con el x,y de cada instancia del mapa...pero notaba que la maquina se calentaba mucho por tantos bucles for..algo mal)

Comment: ¿ Te refieres a que se calentaba "literalmente" ?, o ¿es una expresión que no termino de captar ?

Comment: Se calentaba literalmente, es una macbook pro y no tiene buena ventilación. Pero igual, digo que no es conveniente usar un bucle for de 0 a 500 cada vez que se hace un click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.¿Como diseño bien el tablero? ¿Se hace en un array unidimensional o bi(x-y) cada uno con las instancias de los sprites correspondientes?

No hay mucha diferencia entre hacer:

```
Tile tile = tilesMap[x][y];
```

y esto otro

```
Tile tile = tilesMap[x * width + y];
```

En cuanto a performance, en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2512168/2573335) de SOen, puedes ver que tampoco hay una diferencia sustancial.

Esta decision es mas una cuestión de preferencia personal, que una cuestión técnica. Yo utilizaría la primera, pues ya que genera un bytecodes diferentes y no se sabe si en el futuro puede haber optimizationes especificas.

> ¿A los "tiles" como hago para que tengan un listener del mouse? Hasta ahora ese fue mi mayor problema(se me ocurrió ver el click de mouse x,y y comparado con el x,y de cada instancia del mapa...pero notaba que la maquina se calentaba mucho por tantos bucles for..algo mal)

Lo que yo haría es una función que traduzca las coordenadas de la pantalla a las coordenadas del mapa o tablero.

Es solo una cuestión de escala, si fuera un tablero de ajedrez, la escala es 8 x 8, si se trata de un mundo con scroll y zoom, con un poco de matemática lo calculas, el punto aquí es que las coordenadas de la pantalla y las del trablero estan en diferentes "dominios", por lo tanto necesitas una forma de traducir de un sentido al otro (y viceversa para dibujar).

Con las coordenadas del tablero, sera fácil hallar que hay debajo.

Comment: Claro, pero teniendo un tablero 8x8(que es chico), tendría que hacer un for de 0 a 16 comparando las coordenadas x y del mouse con las de cada sprite, algo que pienso que no es buena idea si tengo un mapa 100x100 o 25x25

Comment: El tamaño no importa tanto a estas escalas, 100x100 son 10000, un for pelado puede hacer 100.000.000 de iteraciones en un segundo. Lo que sige es lo que cuenta, si "lo que hay dentro del for" lleva tiempo sustancial o no.

Comment: Ah mucho más de lo que pensaba. . Genial entonces, voy a hacer como decis.

Comment: @MatiEzelQ en esos casos no tiened que hacer una gran iteración. En su lugar defines el inicio de tus coordenadas x ejm (0,0) y que escalan de 100 en 100 es decir la casilla (0,0) está demarcada por todos los puntos con coordenadas (0,0), (0,100), (100,100) y (100,0). Luego solo aplicas una fórmula matemática (que no recuerdo) para ver si un punto (x,y) corresponde a un plano (el cual ya tienes) y si no corresponde pasas al siguiente. Así tus iteraciones disminuyen de miles al número toral de casillas que tenga tu tablero.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza mi experiencia me dice que transformar las coordenadas es mas limpio, pues no necesitas saber nada del domiño de la pantalla en el juego. Si el Tile _sabe_ el rango de coordenadas en pantalla, y luego reduces la ventana de juego al  50% (por ejemplo), deberías actualizar las coordenadas en el Tile también. En cambio si usas una transformada, toda esa lógica queda ahí dentro.

Comment: Es más, inclusive puedes hacer algo aún mejor: tienes el tamaño de tus dimensiones dX y dY, donde dX es el tamaño de tus casillas en la dimensión X y dY es el tamaño de tus casillas en la dimensión Y. Entonces, puedes hacer una operación en tiempo O(1) (constante) para obtener en qué casilla te encuentras: (x,y) se encontrará en la casilla [x % dX, y % dY] de la matriz o [x % dX * dX + y % dY]. No se necesitan loops.

Comment: Esa sería la transformada más simple, que no incluye scroll ni zoom. Es básicamente la idea.